# Storing AngularJs html templates in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

It looks like Angulars `$templateCache` is simply storing the templates in memory 
- so huge amount of them has significant effect on overall app performance.

I have crazy idea to store all the templates in localStorage and decorate `$templateCache` to use localStorage instead of memory.

My questionis:

1) Does localStorage float in memory in any way or it's always accessed from the disc?

2) Does this seems somehow logical thing to do, knowing templates never change?

Comment: `localstorage` use your browser's installed directory space.

Comment: First ask yourself if that needs to be stored in local storage? Is that even data? I mean does your angular template qualify as Data ? I think maintaining an object itself would be enough unless you want it to be available on next visit in storage.. But I don't see a valid usecase as such..

Comment: There is a very valid reason that the angular developers did not have this crazy idea i guess

Comment: BTW.. Accessing from memory would be a thousand times faster than accessing from Local storage when needed..

Comment: It doesn't need to, well it is data, especially when you have multiple small template files, it might be faster to load them through localStorage then making server requests / getting it. Well also this takes browser cache into the game. But at this point I see that angulars templateCache is just storing templates in memory which does not seem to be ideal for our case. Our app runs huge logics so free memory is pretty crucial... That's why I've got such idea in the first place :)

Comment: would require versioning templates ...  sounds ugly. Not to mention how much memory are you really going to free up? Only templates that have been used get stored if they are resident on server

Comment: How much do your templates weigh, really? 1MB? 10MB? Maybe use some HTML minifier before you create doubtful hacks.

Comment: Well it's not only about the size... It's up to 5mb, but let's say in one page I have 20 angular directives with their own templates, so with one page load it's possible to make 21 html template request. It involves server performance, internet speed as main variables. By putting those templates to localStorage there is potential to save some server resources and to remove internet speed variable... :)

Comment: I'm interested in this too. When using Cordova - it can be helpful to allow the app to render templates when connectivity is not available.